# Paginate and apply in batches to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like:

```
id        sentence
1       "Some txt"
2    "Another txt"
3    "Awkward txt"
4       "Last txt"
...
9273
```

Now I need to get records in **portion by 20 (paginate)**, apply function **that is called once** that returns a list of 20 elements and applies to a DataFrame creating a new column like:

```
id        sentence   parsed
1       "Some txt"     1242
2    "Another txt"     9762
3    "Awkward txt"     9355
4       "Last txt"     4126
...
9273
```

---

Practical use-case scenario: I have an API that can do batch call. I want to take a single column's paginated values, put into that API, wait for response and apply to each row with returned data. I want to call API once, instead of 20x with `.apply()`.

How?

Answer (score 0):

With the following fake API and toy dataframe:

```py
import random
import string

import pandas as pd


def fake_api(l):
    """Takes a list of strings and returns a list of uppercase strings."""
    return [item.upper() for item in l]


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [_ for _ in range(20)],
        "sentence": [
            "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 5)) for _ in range(20)
        ],
    }
)

print(df)
# Output

   sentence
0     iMkCN
1     LUpyw
2     HDwTJ
3     SWjby
4     mqncM
5     AwfaI
6     zdPEB
7     HrFjU
8     RknxK
9     EkDWe
10    mBFfS
11    PNfAq
12    lDJTu
13    OXcmd
14    Mhftl
15    ZpwBO
16    QiVGe
17    DUfVb
18    rNIuQ
19    iqOAr
```

Here is one way to do what you are trying to achieve, if I understand correctly, with Pandas [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), [to_list](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html), and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
CHUNK_SIZE = 5

chunks = [df[i : i + CHUNK_SIZE] for i in range(0, df.shape[0], CHUNK_SIZE)]

new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        chunk.assign(new_sentence=fake_api(chunk["sentence"].to_list()))
        for chunk in chunks
    ]
)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)

# Output
   sentence new_sentence
0     iMkCN        IMKCN
1     LUpyw        LUPYW
2     HDwTJ        HDWTJ
3     SWjby        SWJBY
4     mqncM        MQNCM
5     AwfaI        AWFAI
6     zdPEB        ZDPEB
7     HrFjU        HRFJU
8     RknxK        RKNXK
9     EkDWe        EKDWE
10    mBFfS        MBFFS
11    PNfAq        PNFAQ
12    lDJTu        LDJTU
13    OXcmd        OXCMD
14    Mhftl        MHFTL
15    ZpwBO        ZPWBO
16    QiVGe        QIVGE
17    DUfVb        DUFVB
18    rNIuQ        RNIUQ
19    iqOAr        IQOAR
```